# Convert date format using Altova MapForce

Tags: xml, xslt

Hoping that someone else out there uses Altova Mapforce for formatting dates.

I am trying to convert the date format of my XML file. My XML file has a tag with different values like:

```
<submitTime>2016-06-09T18:27:56+0000</submitTime>
<submitTime>2016-06-09T18:13:10+0000</submitTime>
```

I am using an XSLT stylesheet to convert the date format into form **(YYYY-MM-DD)**

```
 <submitTime>2016-06-09</submitTime>
```

This is my XSLT which I have coded using Altavo Mapforce software.

```
.......
    <submitTime>
       <xsl:sequence select="format-date(xs:date(fn:string(_source/submitTime)), '[y,4-4][M,2-2][D,2-2]', 'en', (), ())"/>
    </submitTime>
.......
```

But when I ran this XSLT with XML using a java program, I am getting this error:

```
FORG0001: Invalid date "2016-06-09T17:38:20+0000" (Value includes time)
```

I am very new to this. I might be missing something. Is there any other way in Altova to convert the date into this format **(YYYY-MM-DD)**. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you simply do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(submitTime, 'T')"/>
```

You will never be able to format the input using the `format-date()` function, because it's not a date, nor the `format-dateTime()` function, because it's not a valid dateTime either (the time offset needs to be in `hh:mm` format).

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I tried it yesterday, but I missed the parent tag and that's why your solution was not working. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to parse it into a MapForce valid Date or DateTime with the function **parse-date** or **parse-dateTime** then you can use **format-date** or **format-dateTime**.

If you don't parse first, MapForce will implicitly parse it and that can fail.